# 508 Resourse Limited on DLE, rss error in Logs

Tags: rss, limit, server, datalife-engine

My hosting COmpany wrote me that they will off my site if I will not improve this issue. 
I looked in logs error and so many time written

```
mod_hostinglimits:Error on LVE enter: LVE(628) HANDLER(x-httpd-php5) HOSTNAME(mevicer.com) URL(/engine/rss.php) TID(742659) errno (7)
```

firs time I turned off rss feed Becouse I thought it need more resourses, but not helped

Comment: WHat is LVE and what does rss.php do?

Comment: I can not understand your question sory

Answer (score 0):

What is your Datalife Engine version? maybe the issue is not from rss live feed but it maybe coming from "RSS informer" try to disable RSS Informer module by go to **site.com/admin.php?mod=options&action=syscon** Database Settings tab and look for "Enable use of RSS informer module" and set it to "No" and clear SmartCache. Good luck

Comment: Version is 10.2. No I am not using rss informet too it in on No already

Comment: In that case it means your server resources are max. like running out of memory, max CPU etc...therefore you have very few options. disable all modules and functions/hacks you don't need to reduce server resources...or find better and stronger server/host because your site is eating server resources.